# Storing user-specific data during a Django session

Tags: django, database

I have a question about database organization in Django.

Let this be, for example, some simple browser game based on the parameters of the characters.
The user creates his own The Fellowship of the Ring from standard characters that have certain initial parameters. At this point, the characters for each user are identical and can be taken from a single table. But during the session, the parameters of each character will change. Between sessions, character data can be stored in JSON. But during the game, unpacking and repacking JSON into the database every time does not sound like a very good idea(a lot of calculations on the server side and a lot of changes to the template on the client side). What's the best way to store user-specific data during a session?

P.S. Of course, I know about Django Sessions, but I’m not sure that this is suitable for the described task